# Cant Save .exe using reflixil and Red Gate Reflector 10.3

Tags: windows

First off all im pretty new to Reverse Engineering.
Im Stuck on Saving my Project.
When i want to save the Assembly as .exe file Reflexil says cant save, the specified Method is not supported.
I tried it even with the untouched original File, and it gets me the same Error.
Pls help im kinda stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yep!  Been there.  It was VERY VERY picky about the order that you did things in, but then I found dnSpy.  (FOSS), grab it, use it, and never look back.

[dnSpy github page](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy)

Answer (score 0):

There is also dotPeek Decompiler - works great
https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/